# How to add subquery to get last record in group by

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I would like assistance with adding a subquery into the below query as I understand this is the method I need to use to get the result from the last record for scan_type column, not the first record in the group by due to mysql server running 5.7.

I have tried doing this but I am not understanding how I can put the subquery into the current query.  I have tried unsuccessfully which causes the query to error.

Currently I am able to get the date/time stamp by using MAX which gives me the last record for the person's attendance, but I am having trouble getting the related "scan_type".  Apart from this, the remainder of the query returns all of the expected results.

Below is the current query:

```
SELECT A.attendance_sessions_id, A.person_id, A.scan_type, A.absence_type, MAX(A.date_time), B.name, B.student_level 
FROM `attendance_record` A 
LEFT JOIN `person` B ON A.person_id = B.student_no 
WHERE A.scan_type IS NULL 
   OR A.scan_type <> 'evac_scan' 
   OR A.scan_type NOT LIKE 'evac_%' 
GROUP BY A.attendance_sessions_id, A.person_id
```

Below is the current output of the above query:

| attendance_sessions_id | person_id | scan_type | absence_type | MAX(A.date_time) | name | student_level |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 65 | scan_in | NULL | 2022-02-06 12:59:48 | Chris | Year 1 |

Expecting scan_type = "scan_out"

attendance_record table:

| attendance_record_id | attendance_sessions_id | person_id | scan_type | absence_type | date_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 1 | 65 | scan_in | NULL | 2022-02-05 20:13:17 |
| 5 | 1 | 65 | scan_out | NULL | 2022-02-05 20:14:39 |
| 6 | 1 | 65 | scan_in | NULL | 2022-02-06 12:06:45 |
| 7 | 1 | 65 | evac_scan | NULL | 2022-02-06 12:53:01 |
| 8 | 1 | 65 | scan_out | NULL | 2022-02-06 12:59:48 |

person table:

| person_id | student_no | name | student_level |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9 | 65 | Chris | Year 1 |

attendance_sessions table:

| attenance_sessions_id | session_name | session_date_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | February Weekend 1 | 2022-02-05 00:01:00 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since some time [only_full_group_by](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) is the default, (at least for MySQL 8+ ). It would be great to change this query in such a way that it's handled correctly, als in the furture.

```
SELECT 
   x.attendance_sessions_id,
   x.person_id,
   A.scan_type,
   A.absence_type,
   x.max_date_time,
   B.name,
   B.student_level
FROM (
   SELECT 
      A.attendance_sessions_id, 
      A.person_id, 
      -- A.scan_type, 
      -- A.absence_type, 
     MAX(A.date_time)  as max_date_time, 
     -- B.name, 
     -- B.student_level 
   FROM `attendance_record` A 
   -- LEFT JOIN `person` B ON A.person_id = B.student_no 
   WHERE A.scan_type IS NULL 
      OR A.scan_type <> 'evac_scan' 
      OR A.scan_type NOT LIKE 'evac_%' 
   GROUP BY 
      A.attendance_sessions_id, 
      A.person_id
) x
INNER JOIN `attendance_record` A ON A.attendance_sessions_id = x.attendance_sessions_id
                                AND A.person_id = x.person_id
                                AND A.date_time = x.max_date_time
LEFT JOIN `person` B ON B.student_no = A.person_id
```

1. Removed some columns (`--`) because of the `only_full_group_by` setting, and removed the `LEFT JOIN` because in the current sub-query the table `person` is no longer used.
2. Changed query to sub-query, and added all (remove)fields to the outer query which also includes a JOIN to get the MAX record from `attendance_record`

NOTE: When there are multiple records with the same `date_time` for one `attendance_sessions_id`,`person_id`, this query will not produce correct results.